# assign an AngularJS variable to a Razor variable in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

assign an AngularJS variable to a Razor variable in ASP.net

```
  $scope.currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
  $scope.model_Year = 2019;

{{model_Year}} - {{currentYear}}

@{
    var a = 1;   //here assign the variable $scope.currentYear
    var b = 1;   //here assign the variable $scope.model_Year 
}

@if (a != b)
{
    <label class="text-bold">RODO</label>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

Razor code is executed/interpreted on the server, while Angular code is executed by the browser in the client - after the Razor code has been executed already.

You can, though, assign Razor variables to Angular variables.

```cs
@{
    int a = Datetime.Now.Year;
    int b = 2019;
}

<script>
    $scope.currentYear = @a;
    $scope.model_Year = @b;
</script>

{{model_Year}} - {{currentYear}}

@if (a != b)
{
    <label class="text-bold">RODO</label>
}
```

The server will execute the Razor code, setting `a = 2020` and `b = 2019`; then it replaces all instances of `@a` with `2020` and `@b` with `2019`.